# Character count per textarea using a foreach loop

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I'm using a foreach loop for my fields and I want to create a character count for each field individually.

here is a sample code from my cs file

```
List<Document> record= _repository.Document.GetChecklist(entity.checklist, Convert.ToInt32(entity.ref)).ToList();

if (record.Count() > 0)
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (var r in record)
            {   
                _html.Append("<tr>");
                _html.Append("<td style=\"padding-left:20px\" class=\"td-control\">
                              <textarea cols=\"50\" rows=\"5\" maxlength=\"1000\" id=\"desc" + i + "\">" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.desc) ? "" : r.desc.ToString().Trim()) + "</textarea>
                              <div id=\"char-count\">
                              <span id=\"current\">0</span><span>/ 1000</span></div></td>"
                _html.Append("</tr>");
                i++;

            }
        }
```

css:

```
#char-count
    {
        float: right;
        padding: 0.1rem 0 0 0;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
    }
```

I tried doing something like this but its not working.

here is my jquery

```
        $("#desc").keyup(function () {
            $("#desc").each(function () {

                var characterCount = $(this).val().length,
                    current = $('#current');

                current.text(characterCount);

            });

        });
```

im sorry im having a hard time trying to explain. im a beginner at coding and my english is not my first language.

Comment: Since `id` (`#`) are necessarily unique, jQuery probably does the right thing by not selecting multiple elements here, which means it indeed only applies to your first element. However,  with the supplied code we are not really able to help you. What is `_html`? Is it the text itself? Does it increase the length? What is `a.Count()`?  _What is `a`?_ Why are you declaring `int i`? That's not JS. If you are using another language than javascript, please specify that with tags. Same for using jQuery, add that tag.

Comment: Sorry just edited my post to add some more clarification on my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<textarea id="desc">` element with an ID, but you are creating multiples in a loop in your C# code.  An ID in HTML can only exist one time for an entire document, it must be a UNIQUE identifier.

If you need multiples, use a class instead: `<textarea class="desc">` and now you can select all of them with the CSS selector `.desc`

Since you need to have multiple textareas and character counts that each need to establish a relationship, I would recommend putting a class on a wrapping parent element and from that you can find the inner elements you need.

```js
//Loop over all these wrapper elements
$(".description-wrapper").each(function() {
  //select the elements we need inside of this wrapper
  const textEl = $(this).find('.desc');
  const countEl = $(this).find('.current-count');
  
  //Determine the character count on a keyup event
  textEl.keyup(function () {
    countEl.text(this.value.length);
  });

  //Trigger the event manually on page load so it has an initial count
  textEl.keyup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="description-wrapper">
      <textarea class="desc">hello world</textarea>
      <p>Char count: <span class="current-count">0</span>/1000</p>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description-wrapper">
      <textarea class="desc"></textarea>
      <p>Char count: <span class="current-count">0</span>/1000</p>
    </td>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description-wrapper">
      <textarea class="desc">foo</textarea>
      <p>Char count: <span class="current-count">0</span>/1000</p>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! this helped me a lot, dont know why i didnt think of using a class instead but thank you for reminding me.